# Django create a new record for each user every month

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

The title is self explanatory. I would like to create a new record for a user at the start of each month. What is the best way to achieve this in Django?

My initial thoughts were to run a function that will check the date time every x amount of intervals and then if year and month of last record != then create a new record. Is this even possible? It seems that this constant checking of time would be inefficient but I am struggling to think of another solution.

Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: Do you need to create the record eagerly? Why not create it when you need it? Exactly what do you aim to do with the record?

Comment: I am building a Net Worth app. I would like the app to track the NetWorth of the User from month to month. It seems to make more sense to do it automatically than to have the user click a button for each month.

Comment: but if the user does not click any button, will there be a change of the data?

Comment: The new record will copy from the last and then be updated as their Net Worth changes. To then to be finally saved at the end of the month and the old record will never updated again. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In web application, the best way to do this is to rely on system task scheduler, like cron in linux, to execute your code at a given time. You can schedule your task every day at midnight, and check for each user if this month's record is there, and create it if it is not there.

Here is an article on how to make cron jobs with django https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/

Comment: So would I write a script that is scheduled and connects via an API to create the record?

Comment: Hmmm no, i'm not expert in django, but I think you can run scripts directly on the server to interact with django without using the API. Check this https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/

Comment: Yes you're right! I think django-background-tasks is what I need. I'm looking into that right now.

Comment: Nice :) let us know if it was helpful when you've suceeded :)